# how to stop if($this->_request->isPost()) if webpage is refreshed?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Good day to you!
I've got a problem:
On the webpage there's a form. it's action points to itself.
But after thhe form is submitted if the webpage is accidentialy refreshed you get form submitted again!
How this can be avoided? didn't find any solutions.

html code:

`<form method="POST" action="" name="new_branch" 
                      onsubmit="return validateForm()">
blah blah blah
</form>`

And on server side

```
 if($this->_request->isPost()) { //code here }
```

How do you "reset" post?

Comment: Redirect to confirmation page after form processing or use tokens

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 10):

To stop submission on refresh you should redirect to any page after processing with the POST request.

In your case, you can redirect on the same page, Zend has a method to redirect

```
$this->_redirect('/controller/action');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AJAX to submit, just change the code this way:

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="new_branch" onsubmit="validateForm(); return false;">
    blah blah blah
</form>
```

Hope this works!